# My comparison operator is not working for PHP in atom

Tags: php, html, forms

I tried to make a comparison between $BMI and number however, it said "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token "<="". I made a change on the operator but still, it said the same thing. This is my code for HTML and PHP.

For HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>BMI Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <form action="BMI.php" method="post">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="">Weight (kg):</label></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="weight" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><label for="">Height (m):</label></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="height" value=""></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <input type="submit" name="calt" value="Calculate">
      <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Clear">
    </form>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

For PHP

```
<?php

$weight = $_POST['weight'];
$height = $_POST['height'];

function calculateBMI(){
  global $weight, $height;
  $total = ($weight/($height*$height))*10000;
  return $total;
}

$BMI = calculateBMI();
echo "Your BMI is ". number_format((float)$BMI,2,'.','');

if ($BMI < 18.5){
  echo "You are underweight";}
elseif (18.5 <= $BMI <= 25 ){
  echo "You are normal weight";}
elseif (26 <= $BMI <= 30){
  echo "You are overweight"}
elseif (31 <= $BMI <= 40){
  echo "You are obese";}
elseif ($BMI > 40){
  echo "Out of bound";}

?>
```

Thank you for helping me ><

Comment: Try splitting up the double comparisons. So change `18.5 <= $BMI <= 25` to `18.5 <= $BMI && $BMI <= 25`

Comment: What would happen if the BMI is 25.5?

Comment: @Tintenfisch, the next one is checked, but 25.5 is less than 26 so that gets skipped...

Comment: @NigelRen Oh wait, I confused $BMI with the actual value (because I am used to always have the variable on the left) *facepalm*.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if the BMI is below or equal to 18.5 but lower than 25, you would use:

```
($BMI <= 18.5 && $BMI < 25)
```

But you don't need these double-checks. That may be what you want:

```
if ($BMI <= 0) {
    echo "BMI must be greater than 0.";
} elseif ($BMI < 18.5) {
    echo "You are underweight";
} elseif ($BMI <= 25) {
    echo "You are normal weight";
} elseif ($BMI <= 30) {
    echo "You are overweight";
} elseif ($BMI <= 40) {
    echo "You are obese";
// $BMI is > 40
} else {
    echo "Out of bound";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `(18.5 <= $BMI <= 25 )` this kind of syntax you can try with `(18.5 <= $BMI && $BMI <= 25 )`.

So your final if-else block will be something like:

```
if ($BMI < 18.5){
  echo "You are underweight";}
elseif (18.5 <= $BMI && $BMI <= 25 ){
  echo "You are normal weight";}
elseif (26 <= $BMI && $BMI <= 30){
  echo "You are overweight"}
elseif (31 <= $BMI && $BMI <= 40){
  echo "You are obese";}
elseif ($BMI > 40){
  echo "Out of bound";}
```